# Simple Bifurcation Question

Tags: dynamical-systems

For the system:

$$
\dot x = r+4x^2
$$

find the value of $r$ at which the bifurcation occurs and classify it.

As far as I'm aware, you can use

$$
f(x^*)=0;
f'(x^*)=0
$$

and then solve for $r$ where $x^*$ is an equillibrium point.

However this doesn't really make sense to me. I know that a bifurcation happens when an equillibrium point is created or destroyed but I don't know how to work out the bifurcation values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilibria for this differential equation are the values of $x$ where the right side $r + 4 x^2 = 0$, namely $x = \pm \sqrt{-r/4}$ if $r \le 0$, but none for $r > 0$.  So the bifurcation happens at $r=0$, and it's a saddle-node bifurcation.

Comment: ah yes, thank you. So the bifurcation at $r=0$ is because there is none for $r>0$. If for another question there were no equllibrium points for values say $r>1$ then the bifurcation point would be $r=1$?

Comment: Yes, if there are no equilibrium points for $r > 1$ but there are for $r < 1$, $r=1$ would be a bifurcation.

Comment: that's perfect. thanks for y our help!

Comment: One last question, how did you know it was a saddle-node bifurcation?

Comment: or how would you know a system was a supercritical pitchfork? Is it upon observation of the bifurcation diagrams?

Comment: In a saddle-node bifurcation, two equilibria collide and disappear.
In a pitchfork bifurcation, one equilibrium becomes three.  Which of these looks like this system?